# How can I sign Intercom framework using MS AppCenter if the pre-build script runs before create-keychain?

Tags: ios, xamarin, codesign, visual-studio-app-center

We've developed a Xamarin iOS app that includes [Intercom](https://github.com/intercom/intercom-ios) installed manually. The issue we're running into is that we need to run their "stripFrameworks.sh" script AND get it to sign the code, as Apple is saying during deploy that the code needs to be signed, but we can't because the pre-build AppCenter script runs BEFORE the create-keychain call on the build server.

[image: Microsoft runs their keychain code during build]

None of the other [AppCenter build scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/custom/scripts/) looks like they'll work (post clone, post build), since they run at the wrong time I think to be meaningful.

How in the world is this supposed to work? As far as I know we didn't have any other option than to include Intercom.framework manually because we needed to create Xamarin native binding library to allow it to be used. It works AMAZINGLY in Ad Hoc releases, simulator and real device but we're only hitting this issue when moving to AppStore deploy.

Comment: You can reach out to App Center support by logging into https://appcenter.ms/apps and clicking the chat icon in the lower right corner of the screen. You could get a better support there. :)

Comment: Here's a screenshot if you're having trouble finding the chat [icon](https://www.screencast.com/t/uF8S5o0o0)

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT That's why I'm here, that support is very very slow and I'm dead in the water.